# Typed object keys by enum - not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

It seems that my type is working as expected. Then can please someone help me to explain the error I get in its definition and how to fix it? I can not find a solution.

```
export enum Languages {
  Cs = 'cs',
  Sk = 'sk',
  En = 'en'
}

export type RouteDefinitionItem<T> = {
  name: string;
  pathname: { [index in T]: string };
  page: string;
};

const routes: RouteDefinitionItem<Languages>[] = [
  {
    name: 'home',
    pathname: {
      cs: '/',
      en: '/en',
      sk: '/sk'
    },
    page: '/home'
  }
];
```

error:

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
```

[Link to TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwDIENEHNla7ADOcA3gFBxwDCpAvHAOQDGxTANFXAMoDWcRk2J9O3AKKJBzJEwoBfChVCRYcGAE8wwOACUIyGMAAiwAGYBLRBZgWIiAJJHUAHgAqAPmmVqiLKmAALjhiGCgrXABubjAsGAALPwDgsjgAbSsAE1A4Kzg3AF1g0PC8OHlo6liiYrCI6IqlFntQuCgDI2Jg-UMTcysbO0dnF2w8AiJiDzSC6TTuH2o4JKDmeIgAsSW4WISVlO5ttmCmAHot7YREE9PZLkuQvhuROW35e6Xq1bP1ze5FArRIA)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't use any `T` for `RouteDefinitionItem`, because only `string | number | symbol` can be properties. So constrain it - `T extends string | number | symbol`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank @jonrsharpe, now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export enum Languages {
    Cs = 'cs',
    Sk = 'sk',
    En = 'en'
}



export type RouteDefinitionItem<T extends keyof any > = {
    name: string;
    pathname: Record<T,string>;
    page: string;
};

const routes: RouteDefinitionItem<Languages>[] = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        pathname: {
          'cs':'',
          'en':'',
          'sk':''
        },
        page: '/home'
    }
];
```

UPDATED.

Comment: Thank you for answer. However I am more happy with @jonrsharpe answer since I really want to use values of the enum.

Comment: @TomášVavřinka UPDATED. That probably you wanted.